# Starting Apache and MySql in XAMPP slows internet to a crawl (or disconnects completely)

Tags: windows, internet, apache-http-server, mysql, xampp

When I start Apache and MySql from XAMPP as I've always done (in Windows 7), I've recently started running into a problem where internet stops working or works very slowly.

So I have to turn it on, use `http://localhost` and when I need to check something online I have to turn Apache and MySql off, and then back again.

I'm using a default configuration of XAMPP, and here is some version information:

- OS: Windows 7
- XAMPP: 1.7.3
- Apache: 2.2.14
- MySQL 5.1.41

Please let me know if you have suggestions for fixing this issue or diagnosing the possible source of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) and see what is running through your ethernet interface, one of these aplications may be trying to connect somewhere and taking a long or infinite timeouts. Concomitantly see in your [windows eventviewer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427) and make a search for the events that are happening when this problem occours, you should have something misconfigured on Apache.